# Colocar un <div> o <span> con jquery sobre una palabra

Tags: jquery

Hola estoy tratando de separar un texto en varias palabras.Pero no logro colocar correctamente el span o div sobre cada una de las palabras
He intentado esto:

```js
$(function () {
  $("body").find("p").on("click", function (evento) { 
      let parrafo = $("body").find("p").text().trim(); 
      let espacio = (' ');
      var array = parrafo.split(espacio);
      
      console.log(array);

      $("body").find("p").each(array,function(i,e){
        array[i]= $('p').append("<span>"+ e +"</span>");
        
        });
     });
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hola esto es un texto que quiero separar. Quiero añadir Span o divs en cada palabra</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se usó la instrucción `for` para recorrer cada letra de la oración dentro de la `etiqueta` de `párrafo`, el único detalle que tienes que contemplar es que al final de la oración que escribas, pongas un **espacio** ya que si no lo pones, la última palabra no te la va a tomar.

Si inspeccionas el código, te darás cuenta que a cada palabra le agrega las etiquetas `span` de apertura y cierre.

Pruébalo.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      
      var palabras = "<span>";
          var tamaño_palabra = $('p').html().length;
          var texto = $('p').html();
          var cadena_nueva ="";


          for(var i = 0; i < tamaño_palabra; i++){

              palabras += texto[i];

              if(texto[i] == " "){

                  palabras += "</span>";
                  cadena_nueva += palabras;
                  palabras = "<span>";
              }
          }

          $('p').html(cadena_nueva);
    
    });
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<p>Hola esto es un texto que quiero separar. Quiero añadir Span o divs en cada palabra </p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: me puedes explicar esto que hace exactamente ? palabras += "</span>";
                  cadena_nueva += palabras;
                  palabras = "<span>";   Es que no termino de entenderlo. Porque primero la etiqueta de cierre?

Comment: @WinterIsBack OK, la `palabras += "</span>";`  se pone para cerrar la etiqueta `<span>` una vez que haya terminado la primer palabra encontrada, después la palabra que se guardó, se va almacenando en  `cadena_nueva += palabras;` y finalmente la variable `palabras = "<span>";` se vuelve a setear con la etiqueta de apertura `span` para meter la siguiente palabra, y así consecutivamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! :) ahora si lo entiendo!!